# Listview on Fragment not showing

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

i just made a custom listview with asynctask in my fragment. i dont know where is the problem, because on logcat never showing errors. please someone can help me

This is my Fragment Code

```
public static class ListAnak extends Fragment{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private MenuItem newDataAnak;
    private ListView listView;
    private FroListAnakAdapter adapter;
    private Streamer streamer;
    private JSONArray jsonArray;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fro_listanak, container, false);
         adapter  = new FroListAnakAdapter(new ArrayList<Anak>(), getActivity());
            listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            (new Asyncronous()).execute();
        return rootView;
    }

private class Asyncronous extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Anak>> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected List<Anak> doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<Anak> result = new ArrayList<Anak>();
        try {
            List<NameValuePair>nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("aksi", "dataanak"));
            jsonArray = streamer.postData(VariabelGlobal.url+"/anak.php", nameValuePairs);
            for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                result.add(convertContact(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)));
            }

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Anak> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        adapter.setItemList(result);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    private Anak convertContact(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        String FullName = obj.getString("nama");
        String Username = obj.getString("username");
        String AnakKe = obj.getString("anakke");            
        return new Anak(FullName, Username, AnakKe);
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.act_data_anak, menu);
     }

        @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_addanak:
                newDataAnak = item;
                NewData();
                return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

        private void NewData() {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AddAnak.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
}
```

And This is my custom adapter

```
    package com.app.amusa.library;


import com.app.amusa.R;
import com.app.amusa.library.*;
//import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie;

import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class FroListAnakAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Anak> {

private List<Anak> itemList;
private Context context;

public FroListAnakAdapter(List<Anak> itemList, Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.context = ctx;     
}

public int getCount() {
    if (itemList != null)
        return itemList.size();
    return 0;
}

public Anak getItem(int position) {
    if (itemList != null)
        return itemList.get(position);
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (itemList != null)
        return itemList.get(position).hashCode();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_anak, null);
    }

    Anak c = itemList.get(position);
    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.FullName);
    text.setText(c.getFullName());

    TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Username);
    text1.setText(c.getUsername());

    TextView text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.AnakKe);
    text2.setText(c.getAnakKe());


    return v;

}

public List<Anak> getItemList() {
    return itemList;
}

public void setItemList(List<Anak> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
}


}
```

and this serializable code

```
  package com.app.amusa.library;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Anak implements Serializable  {
    private String FullName, thumbnailUrl,Username,AnakKe;

public Anak(String FullName,String Username, String AnakKe) {
    this.FullName = FullName;
    this.Username = Username;
    this.AnakKe = AnakKe;       
}

public String getFullName() {
    return FullName;
}

public void setFullName(String FullName) {
    this.FullName = FullName;
}

public String getthumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setthumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return Username;
}

public void setUsername(String Username) {
    this.Username = Username;
}

public String getAnakKe() {
    return AnakKe;
}

public void setAnakKe(String AnakKe) {
    this.AnakKe= AnakKe;
}
}
```

and streamer is custom json was i made.
anyone can help me?
thanks

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to see if you're actually loading the data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you aren't add items correctly to adapter. Try adding with this method

```
public class FroListAnakAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Anak> {
...
public void setItemList(List<Anak> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;

    for(Anak anak: itemList) {
       this.add(anak);
    }

    /** OR  **/
    this.addAll(itemList);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your ListAnak must extend ListFragment & your layout must contain a default fragment listview with android default id attribute. I think that this must work for u. I you need further help then reply to me.